# Remove Page Name from Pages (SharePoint 2013 Page Layout)

Tags: 2013, master-page, navigation, page-layout, breadcrumb

I have a some page layouts that all use the default breadcrumb code (also in same placeholder inside master page):

```
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb
                                runat="server"
                                RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                                SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider"
                                CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">-->
    <!--PS: Start of READ-ONLY PREVIEW (do not modify)--><span id="ctl00_DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">Home</span><!--PE: End of READ-ONLY PREVIEW-->
    <!--SPM:<PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
    <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
    <!--SPM:</SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>-->
    <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
    <!--ME:</PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>-->
    <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
<!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

When I am for example in "System Settings" (System pages use the same master page as "normal" pages). The breadcrumb looks good:

```
System Settings > Content Types
```

But when I am on a Page (Pages Library, for example `../Pages/pageXy.aspx`) the breadcrumb doesn't show me the navigation, it rather looks like this (without brackets):

```
[Page Name without extension] [Page Title]
```

I'm confused, why doesn't it show the library name (as link) and then just the page title. I don't need the page name there (clickable).

The default seattle master page and page layouts show the breadcrumb the way I want them to but I don't see any difference in the breadcrumb code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that I need to use another control to achieve the results I wanted.

With this snippet inside the page layout (eg inside the `PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea` placehoder) it renders me the path nicely to the current page/element:

```
<h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle">
    <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">-->
        <!--MS:<asp:sitemappath runat="server" sitemapproviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider" rendercurrentnodeaslink="true" hideinteriorrootnodes="false">-->
        <!--ME:</asp:sitemappath>-->
    <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
    <!--SPM:<PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
    <!--SPM:<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="&gt;"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>-->
    <!--SPM:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
        <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ListProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>-->
    <!--SPM:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
</h1>
```